# Typescript - How to cast an object from a promise

Tags: typescript, promise, casting, next.js13

I am trying to figure out how to cast an object from an API call (NextJs 13 Fetch).

I am trying to call Sanity with a fetch in a utility method and return the object (Post) to the page, where I can access the properties on the Post object.

Here is the code I have....

## Page Code

```
/* Get the blog post */
const post = async () => {
    await getPost('test-post');
  };
```

## Utility Method

```
export async function getPost(slug:string): Promise <Post> {

    return SanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == "post"] | order(publish_date desc)`,)
}
```

## Post Object

```
import { PortableTextBlockComponent } from "@portabletext/react"
import { Author } from "./Author";
import { Category } from "./Category";
import { BannerImage } from "./BannerImage";

export type Post = {
    title: string,
    headline: string,
    slug: string,
    publish_date: Date,
    banner_image: BannerImage,
    category: Category[],
    author: Author[];
    body: PortableTextBlockComponent[]
};
```

Thanks in advance for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of the workings of your fetch client, several you have to parse the response as json, but assuming you've already done that, then you can cast pretty much anything in typescript via `as unknown as [type]`. So your return from your API call becomes:

**UtilityMethod**

```
export async function getPost(slug:string): Promise <Post> {

    return SanityClient.fetch(`*[_type == "post"] | order(publish_date desc)`,) as unknown as Post;
}
```

Make sure you TEST to verify the returned value is a valid Post.

Comment: Thanks... I dont have the parsing to JSON.  What would that look like?